# VBA - the same formatting for multiple dynamic ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I want to format data in 2 columns in the same pattern. Each data column has its length based on upper boundary of result array. I initially formatted them both separately and it was working as intended, but I want to keep the code as lean as possible.

I tried the code below, but it created a range from 1st range to the 2nd instead of matching a sum of these ranges:

```
With statsWS
    With Range(.Range("b2:c" & UBound(vGoals) + 1), _
               .Range("e2:f" & UBound(vAssists) + 1))
        With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = rgbGrey
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Use Application.Union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Chris Neilsen's suggestion:

```
With statsWS
    With Union(.Range("B2:C" & UBound(vGoals) + 1), .Range("E2:F" & UBound(vAssists) + 1))
        With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = rgbGrey
        End With
    End With
End With
```

But if you want to keep your code lean then you could pass the ranges to another Subroutine to handle the formatting.  Separating the business logic from the display:

### Usage:

`ApplyBorders .Range("B2:C" & UBound(vGoals) + 1), .Range("E2:F" & Bound(vAssists) + 1)`

### Code:

```
Sub ApplyBorders(ParamArray Ranges())
    Dim x As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Ranges(0)

    For x = 1 To UBound(Ranges())
        Set r = Union(r, Ranges(x))
    Next

    With r.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = rgbGrey
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: Because ApplyStandardBorders uses a ParamArray you can pass anywhere from 0 to 60 parameters to it (Only 29 in Excel 2003).

Comment: Do you know if looping through these ranges and applying formatting for each can be less efficient than using Union or other methods mentioned and applying it only once?

Comment: With just two ranges, you wouldn't notice the difference.  I updated my answer to union the ranges.  Your workbook will perform better if you used the built in styles or made a custom style of your own.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
With statsWS.Range("b2:c" & (UBound(vGoals) + 1) & ",e2:f" & (UBound(vAssists) + 1)).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = rgbGrey
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the `Range("Address1,Address2")` method to get the union of different ranges

```
With statsWS
    With .Range(.Range("b2:c" & UBound(vGoals) + 1).Address & "," & .Range("e2:f" & UBound(vAssists) + 1).Address).Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = rgbGrey
    End With
End With
```

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk, did you get through it?